# More threads contemporary

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to run a code, with multiple threads, the user can decide how many threads he wants to run. I tried doing it with the threading module in Python 3.7

My code is shown below, but my problem is, instead of running all the threads together, it runs one after the other...

```
import threading

x=int(input("Enter number of threads: "))

def main():
   print("My main function")
   print("Does some stuff...")
while x > 0:
    print("Starting Threads.")
    x=x-1       #At every time the while loops gets passed, x gets decremented, so once it hits 0 it stops

    t1=threading.Thread(target=main) #for every time the loop passes, a new thread gets created
    t1.start() #and the thread starts here
```

Now I need to find out, how can I make it, that they run at the same time, not one after the other. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code runs in parallel (note: just on one single core though; that is a python limitation due the global interpreter lock).

to make it more obvious change your main function a little; the way it is right now it just finishes too quickly. i suggest:

```
from time import sleep
from random import random

def main():
   print("main starting")
   sleep(random())
   print("main done")
```

this will output something like

```
Enter number of threads: 4
Starting Threads.
main starting
Starting Threads.
main starting
Starting Threads.
main starting
Starting Threads.
main starting
main done
main done
main done
main done
```